# print info in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, data-science, writer

I have a program that prints information from a website, but I want to put this information in a csv or excel file. This is what I did:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import xlsxwriter


workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('nossarede.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

request = requests.get("http://www.drogariasnossarede.com.br/nossas-lojas")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_='item')

for container in data:
  Pharmacyname = container.find_all("h3")
  Pharmacyadd  = container.find_all("p")
  for pharmacy in Pharmacyname:
      print(pharmacy.text)
      for add in Pharmacyadd:
          print(add.text)
      print('')
```

Until here is perfect, it prints perfectly in the way I want. Then I tried this:

```
    import csv
    with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
        writer = csv.writer(ofile)
        for container in data:
            Pharmacyname = container.find_all("h3")
            Pharmacyadd  = container.find_all("p")
            for pharmacy in Pharmacyname:
                for add in Pharmacyadd:
                    writer.writerow((pharmacy.text[0], add.text[1]))
```

But its not working. 
It shows this:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I do it??
Thanks!

Comment: Show your error

Comment: Share the error (if you get one) please.

Comment: Just edited! Thanks for reminding me to put it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file in the byte mode with  `wb`.

Just change this:

`with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:`

for

`with open('names.csv', 'w') as ofile:`

One more thing. Your `writerow` is wrong. You are getting only the first character of the strings.

Change this:

```
 writer.writerow((pharmacy.text[0], add.text[0]))
```

for:

```
writer.writerow((pharmacy.text, add.text))
```

Comment: It solves the TypeError, but now it returns to me an empty csv file (and the print is not empty, so the problem is not missing information)

Comment: I just edited the answer. Try to do the changes I suggested. Here it worked!

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
```

which is write bytes mode, to:

```
with open('names.csv', 'w') as ofile:
```

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import xlsxwriter

request = requests.get("http://www.drogariasnossarede.com.br/nossas-lojas")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div", class_='item')

import csv
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    for container in data:
        Pharmacyname = container.find_all("h3")
        Pharmacyadd  = container.find_all("p")
        for pharmacy in Pharmacyname:
            for add in Pharmacyadd:
                writer.writerow((pharmacy.text, add.text))
```

Comment: It solves the TypeError, but now it returns to me an empty csv file (and the print is not empty, so the problem is not missing information).

Comment: try again. i also changed it so it would eliminate the spaces between the lines, deal with the `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x90' in position 48: character maps to <undefined>`. And did you only want the first letter and 2 nd letter in pharmacy text and add text? I changed that so you get the full text